# How to implement data compression in Redis written from R with rredis to reduce memory usage?

Tags: r, redis, compression, rstudio

I need to compress data stored in Redis. I write the data from R (with package rredis) to Redis like this:

```
redisSet("x","{\"email\":\"master@disaster.com\",\"Ranking\":[{\"Number\":37665,\"rank\":1},{\"Number\":41551,\"rank\":2},{\"Number\":21684,\"rank\":3},{\"Number\":35946,\"rank\":4}]}")
```

Instead of 4 elements in the list of this value there will be 4000 in the real scenario and 70000 keys like that in total. At the moment each of these keys take ~0.15 MB.

I read that it is possible to compress the memory usage of those entries in Redis significantly, e.g. with algorithms like LZO or Snappy. But I could not find information about the concrete implementation. 
Some suggestions to solve the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way for that.

However, Redis can store binary data, so you can compress your data with any preferred compression algorithm, and store the compressed binary data to Redis. When reading the data, you need to get the binary data, and decompress it with the same compression algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your respond! I managed to do so :) I will post a detailed answer with the functions and the level of improvement after a complete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint! I was able to implement it, here are some details:

I used a compression function implemented in R (base package), as suggested.

```
memCompress()
```

I tried different compressions gzip and bzip2.

```
memCompress(type="gzip",...)
memCompress(type="bzip2",...)
```

Here is the code with a toy example:

```
#In R:
x<-"{\"email\":\"master@disaster.com\",\"Ranking\":[{\"Number\":37665,\"rank\":1},{\"Number\":41551,\"rank\":2},{\"Number\":21684,\"rank\":3},{\"Number\":35946,\"rank\":4}]}"
y<-memCompress(charToRaw(x),type="gzip")
# [1] 78 9c 4d c9 3d 0a 80 20 00 06 d0 bb 7c b3 04 e6 4f e5 d4 09 1a 5a a3 c1 4a 42 ca 02 ad 29 bc 7b 11 48 6d 0f de 05 e3 b4 5d a1 e0 74 38 8c
# [47] af 27 1b 5e 64 e3 ee 40 d0 ea 6d b1 db 0c d5 5d 68 4e 37 18 0f c5 0a 29 05 81 7f 0a 8a 46 f2 0d a7 42 d0 34 f9 7f 72 2a 4b 9e 86 fd 87 89
# [93] 8a cb 34 3c f6 f1 06 b3 67 2d c4
rawToChar(memDecompress(y,type="gzip"))
# [1] "{\"email\":\"master@disaster.com\",\"Ranking\":[{\"Number\":37665,\"rank\":1},{\"Number\":41551,\"rank\":2},{\"Number\":21684,\"rank\":3},{\"Number\":35946,\"rank\":4}]}"  



# R to redis:
redisConnect(host="XXX.XX.XX.XXX", port=XXXX, timeout =10) # Insert your redis information (IP and port)
x<-"{\"email\":\"master@disaster.com\",\"Ranking\":[{\"Number\":37665,\"rank\":1},{\"Number\":41551,\"rank\":2},{\"Number\":21684,\"rank\":3},{\"Number\":35946,\"rank\":4}]}"
redisSet("x",x) #Wrong transfer of character string to redis
# redis-cli # On redis server
# get x # On redis server
# "X\n\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x03\x03\x02\x00\x02\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x04\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x93{\"email\":\"master@disaster.com\",\"Ranking\":[{\"Number\":37665,\"rank\":1},{\"Number\":41551,\"rank\":2},{\"Number\":21684,\"rank\":3},{\"Number\":35946,\"rank\":4}]}"
redisSet("x",charToRaw(x)) #Right transfer of character string to redis
# redis-cli # On redis server
# get x # On redis server
# "{\"email\":\"master@disaster.com\",\"Ranking\":[{\"Number\":37665,\"rank\":1},{\"Number\":41551,\"rank\":2},{\"Number\":21684,\"rank\":3},{\"Number\":35946,\"rank\":4}]}"
redisSet("x",memCompress(charToRaw(x),type="gzip")) #Right transfer of compressed string to redis
# redis-cli # On redis server
# get x # On redis server
# "x\x9cM\xc9=\n\x80 \x00\x06\xd0\xbb|\xb3\x04\xe6O\xe5\xd4\t\x1aZ\xa3\xc1JB\xca\x02\xad)\xbc{\x11Hm\x0f\xde\x05\xe3\xb4]\xa1\xe0t8\x8c\xaf'\x1b^d\xe3\xee@\xd0\xeam\xb1\xdb\x0c\xd5]hN7\x18\x0f\xc5\n)\x05\x81\x7f\n\x8aF\xf2\r\xa7B\xd04\xf9\x7fr*K\x9e\x86\xfd\x87\x89\x8a\xcb4<\xf6\xf1\x06\xb3g-\xc4"

# I have not implemented the reimport to R yet. So feel free to add it :)
```

There is no improvement for this short string. But for the long version (4000 instead of 4 elements in the json file) there was a huge improvement:

Compression gives an improvement by ~85% in memory usage and writing time in this case!

Compressed:
Time to write 500 users with 4.000 elements each to redis: 12.62 sec
Memory kept by 500 users with 4.000 elements each on redis: 11.782 MB

Uncompressed:
Time to write 500 users with 4.000 elements each to redis: 88.76 sec
Memory kept by 500 users with 4.000 elements each on redis: 78.192 MB